# Should all object variables be optional in Swift?

Tags: swift

Swift Programming Language book doesn't discuss this but should all object variables be optional in Swift? Because technically speaking, an object creation can fail and return `nil` (as in the case of Objective-C).  So should all object variables in Swift for Swift classes (or at least for all Foundation classes) be declared as optional?

```
let obj:NSData? = NSData()
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be opinion based but I think that usually you want variables to be non-optional.
There are not many objects initializers that can actually return a `nil`.

In Obj-C you don't check whether all initialisers return `nil`.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];

if (array != nil) {  //would you test this?
}
```

In the same way, don't let all object variables be optional in Swift. Only the ones when you actually want to check for `nil` values.

By the way, in pure Swift the Object initializers can't return a `nil` because they don't actually have a return value. In Swift, the object initialization can't fail, so we are speaking only about Obj-C interoperability here.

**One example to answer the comments:**

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"some_file"];
```

in Swift:

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfFile: "some_file")
```

If the file doesn't exist, in both languages we get a `nil`. In Swift, we have an implicitly unwrapped optional, so the assignment itself won't fail and we can still test for `nil` if we want to.

If we expected `data` could be `nil`, the behavior would be the same in both languages, we would solve the problem somehow. If we haven't expected it, it's a bug because everything else is *undefined behavior*.

In Swift, the application will crash early - the first time you try to use `data`.
In Obj-C, the result will be absolutely random - note that we never expected `data` to be `nil`, so our next statement could be:

```
[array addObject:data];
```

crashing the application.

However, because of the nature of Obj-C, thousands of statements could happen before the bug actually reveals itself and it can reveal itself very strangely - for example: data parsing could fail, UI layout will fail because items will be missing when we expected them and so on. We could also get a late crash. Nevertheless, the application behavior will be undefined since the `nil` return because we didn't account for that possibility:

> ...things may not be executed, but it certainly won't crash the program or leave things in an unstable state...

Both statements from the comment are false.

The late manifestation of errors is one of the biggest problems when debugging Obj-C applications, making them unsafe. Sometimes they don't crash but that doesn't mean they are working correctly. Swift considers and early crash a much better alternative than a hidden `nil` object propagating itself through the application and crashing the app hours later.

Comment: I won't test it in Objective-C because it allows it to be nil and it won't cause any issue when it is ni.  But the same cannot be said with Swift.  If you get a nil object and assign it to a non-optional, things is going to blow up in runtime in Swift right?

Comment: in both cases it's unexpected behavior. in objc you will overlook it. in swift you will get a crash and you can fix it.

Comment: I won't really equate them.  If I code in Objective-C, I fully expect the code will run fine even when it's nil.  In the case of ObjC, things may not be executed, but it certainly won't crash the program or leave things in an unstable state.  If there is a possibility of a crash, I would be performing nil check like you have above.

Comment: @Boon I added an answer to your comment to my answer.